Microsoft Graph API read email from not signed in user
I'm looking for help in solving a problem I've run into. I have an app registered at Azure with given permission User.Read and Mail.Read and have tried following different tutorials for reading an users email.
However, the mailbox I'm trying to access is not the mailbox of the signed in user as seem to be the assumption in the tutorials, but an external mail account. How can I grant access to the application to access the external email's mailbox without it being the signed in user? Is this even possible? The external email is added as a member of the group the app belongs to in Azure.
Following documentation from Microsoft I've tried using this for reading the email
from msgraph import GraphServiceClient
from msgraph.generated.users.item.messages.messages_request_builder import MessagesRequestBuilder
from kiota_abstractions.base_request_configuration import RequestConfiguration

scopes = ['User.Read']

# Multi-tenant apps can use "common",
# single-tenant apps must use the tenant ID from the Azure portal
tenant_id = 'common'

# Values from app registration
client_id = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'

# User name and password
username = 'adelev@contoso.com'
password = 'Password1!'

# azure.identity
credential = UsernamePasswordCredential(
    tenant_id=tenant_id,
    client_id=client_id,
    username=username,
    password=password)

graph_client = GraphServiceClient(credential, scopes)

query_params = MessagesRequestBuilder.MessagesRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(
        select = ["sender","subject"],
)

request_configuration = RequestConfiguration(
query_parameters = query_params,
)

result = await graph_client.me.messages.get(request_configuration = request_configuration)

But I don't get anything out of this. I've also tried with msal and tokens
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=CLIENT_ID,
    client_credential=CLIENT_SECRET,
    authority=AUTHORITY)

result = None

result = app.acquire_token_silent(SCOPE, account=None)
  
if not result:
    print("No suitable token exists in cache. Let's get a new one from Azure Active Directory.")
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=SCOPE)


    if "access_token" in result:

        # userID taken from Azure
        endpoint = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/messages$select=sender,subject'
        r = requests.get(endpoint,
                        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']})
        if r.ok:
            print('Retrieved emails successfully')
            data = r.json()
            for email in data['value']:
                print(email['subject'] + ' (' + email['sender']
                    ['emailAddress']['name'] + ')')
         else:
             print(r.json())

This gives me:
 {'error': {'code': 'ErrorAccessDenied', 'message': 'Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.'}}.


Could you please confirm whether that external email is personal Microsoft account like Outlook? Please edit your question and add API permissions screenshot of your app registration.


Note that: Mail.Read and User.Read API permissions allows you to access only signed in user mails and details not other users.

The error "ErrorAccessDenied" usually occurs if the access token does not contain the required API permissions to perform the action.
Hence to resolve the error, you need to grant Mail.ReadBasic.All application type API permission to the Microsoft Entra ID application:

Now generate the access token:
import msal
import requests

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id="ClientID",
    client_credential="Secret",
    authority="https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID"
)

# Acquire a token
result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"])

if "access_token" in result:
    print("Access Token:")
    print(result['access_token'])
else:
    print("Error acquiring token:")
    print(result.get("error"))
    print(result.get("error_description"))
    print(result.get("correlation_id"))  



Decoded token:

Now make use of below query to fetch user’s messages:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/messages$select=sender,subject


 if "access_token" in result:

        # userID taken from Azure
        endpoint = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/messages$select=sender,subject'
        r = requests.get(endpoint,
                        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']})
        if r.ok:
            print('Retrieved emails successfully')
            data = r.json()
            for email in data['value']:
                print(email['subject'] + ' (' + email['sender']
                    ['emailAddress']['name'] + ')')
         else:
             print(r.json())


As I do not have license in my environment, I cannot fetch mails. After the above changes you will be able to access mails of other users.*
Reference:
Get message - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft
